# Searchable Ring Buffer

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, stl, std

I was wondering if someone could suggest a c++ data structure that has both the capabilities of a Ring Buffer (guaranteed finite storage) but at the same time would allow the efficient thread-safe searching of the Ring Buffer for a specified data?

Comment: Can you give us a use case?  There might be a better way to do this.

Comment: I've implemented this exact thing using boost::multi_index. See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: Sure, I have MarketDataDepth (MDD - several bids and asks) coming in. Each MDD is tagged by a unint64_t, MDDTag. I need to store a few of the MDDs (hence the RingBuffer), and then if an Order needs to be sent, the MDDTag will be given, and I need to find the MDD that  is mapped by that MDDTag to extract certain properties from the MDD, hence the need to efficiently search the RB.

Comment: Since data can be comming in at the same time the RingBuffer can be searched, the whole thing needs to be thread-safe.

Comment: Is boost::multi_index guaranteed finite storage?

Comment: How big is the buffer?  Is MDD flat?  (ie, does reading or reaching MDD involve following pointers)?  Is blocking acceptable?  How common are reads vs writes, and whose performance matters more?  What is your elimination strategy when the container over fills?  How important is maintainability?

Comment: The MDD itself can be any size, but say the RingBuffer needs to hold 50 of these MDDs depths. It is basically a std::vector so yes flat. Blockng is acceptable but undesired. Reads are far far far rarer than writes. What overflow, it is a ring buffer?

Comment: @user1676605: Overflow in a ring buffer is, as I understand it, when the next write pointer equals the read pointer. IE, the buffer is full.

Comment: Why C++, this can be done perfectly in C with `pthread` locking.

Comment: "...need to store a few..." how many is a few? "...need to find the MDD..." what happens if it was already overwritten? What do the MDDTag values look like (type, value range)?

Answer (score 2):

The [Intel TBB containers](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/reference/containers_overview.htm) are great for this kind of problem.

The `concurrent_unordered_map` should do the deed for your case, but if you really want some ring structure, you can probably use the `concurrent_bounded_queue` and make your own push to emulate ring behavior (see below). However, you will get a linear search complexity with this structure, not a logarithmic one as in the map.

```
template<class T>
struct concurrent_ring : tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<T>
{
    void push(const T& t) 
    {
        while(!tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<T>::try_push(t)) 
           pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Question about your code: Is inheriting from TBB containers ok? The destructors don't seem to be virtual, so I guess there are similar risks as when deriving from `std` containers?

Comment: Yes, inheriting is ok in this specific case as we only overload a function member, but composing with a `concurrent_bounded_queue`member would be a better design. It was just shorter this way ^^ And I still think using the map would be best for the question case.